# Create a Date structure

Tags: c++, struct

The question asked me to create a structure named Date having day, month and year as its elements. Store the current date in the structure. Now add 45 days to the current date and display the final date.

I wrote the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Date {
    int days;
    int months;
    int years;
};
int main() {
    Date date1;
    cout << "Enter the day of the date " << endl;
    cin >> date1.days;
    while (date1.days > 31) {
        cout << "The days can't be more than 31" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the day of the date " << endl;
        cin >> date1.days;
        }
    cout << "Enter the month of the date " << endl;
    cin >> date1.months;
    while (date1.months > 12) {
        cout << "The month can't be more than 12" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the month of the date " << endl;
        cin >> date1.months;
    }
    cout << "Enter the year of the date " << endl;
    cin >> date1.years;
    cout << "The date is " << date1.days << "/" << date1.months << "/" << date1.years<<endl;
    date1.months++;
    date1.days+15;
    if (date1.months == 12) {
        date1.months = 1;
        date1.years++;
    }
    if (date1.days==27) {
        date1.days = 10;
    }
    if (date1.days == 28) {
        date1.days =11;
    }
    if (date1.days == 29) {
        date1.days = 12;
    }
    if (date1.days == 30) {
        date1.days = 13;
    }
    if (date1.days == 31) {
        date1.days = 14;
    }
    cout << "The date after adding 45 days is " << date1.days << "/" << date1.months <<"/"<< date1.years;
}
```

The if statments is not working at all,why and what should I do?

Comment: You are tasked with adding 45 days, but there seems to be no mention of "45" in your code.  Are you assuming that incrementing the month, plus 5 days would total 45 days?

Comment: This might be better on the [Code Review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I suggest you take this as an oportunity to learn how to debug your programs. With a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. This will help you see what is going on.

Comment: @JDługosz it would be off-topic on CR given "_The if statments is not working at all_"

Comment: In any case, that code won't work.  Regardless of the starting day of the month, it sets the result equal to a constant based on the month.

Comment: And I really recommend that you sit down with a pen and some paper to think more about the logic of your program. Because now the logic just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you explain how you concluded that "if statements are not working at all"?  It's a safe bet that they are working correctly.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add another 10 days lol, I assume that all of the months have 30 days so 45 days means 1 month and "15" days, so yeah I know my answer would be wrong but what I mean about the "If statement isn't wrong" is that it's not working at all when I for example input 28 as the day it gives me 7, and I wrote if the day equals 28 make it 2, thats why I asked why the if statement isn't working

Answer (score 1):

`date1.days+15;` is a no-op, the result is discarded immediately, and `days` is not altered.  Use the `+=` operator instead:

```cpp
date1.days += 15;
```

In any case, the way you are incrementing the date is really inaccurate.  Try something more like the following instead (I'm sure there are more efficient ways to implement this, but thing should give you an idea):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    return (
        ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) ||
        (year % 400 == 0)
    );
}

int lastDayOf(int month, int year)
{
    if (month == 2)
        return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        return 30;
    else
        return 31;
}

struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    Date& operator+=(int days)
    {
        // TODO: handle a negative value for subtracting days...
        int d = day + days;
        int lastDay = lastDayOf(month, year);
        while (d > lastDay)
        {
            d -= lastDay;
            if (++month == 13)
            {
                ++year;
                month = 1;
            }
            lastDay = lastDayOf(month, year);
        }
        day = d;
        return *this;
    }

    // TODO: implement operator-=() for subtracting days...
};

istream& operator>>(istream &in, Date &d)
{
    if (in >> d.day >> d.month >> d.year)
    {
        if (d.month < 1 || d.month > 12 ||
            d.day < 1 || d.day > lastDayOf(d.month, d.year))
        {
            in.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}

int main() {
    Date date1;

    cout << "Enter the day, month, and year of the date" << endl;
    while (!(cin >> date1))
    {
        cout << "Invalidate date!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Enter a new day, month, and year of the date" << endl;
    }

    date1 += 45;

    cout << "The date after adding 45 days is " << date1.day << "/" << date1.month << "/" << date1.year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## general structure

Separate the Input, work and Output into separate functions.  The real meat should be a function that takes the input (the date) and returns the result (another date).

Then you can have an interactive driver like your `main` which prompts the user, OR a set of pre-coded examples to automatically try without you having to type them every time.  It can check the result automatically, too!

## the algorithm

Your code simply doesn't work.  You are not adding 45 days.  You need to have an understanding of what you are going to do before expressing it in the coding language.

Think about "overflow and carry".

## you tagged it as `oop`

There is nothing object-oriented about this.  If it's meant to be an exercise concerning object-oriented programming, you are nowhere close.