# Program gets frozen because of a loop

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

I'm making a program which calculates the date by giving the program a date and number of days to add to that date in input. In order to do this, I need to make a switch and make it repeat with a loop, but for some reasons, the program gets frozen and doesn't do anything after the user inserts the number of days to add. I've tried removing loop and the program works.
Looking forward to someone who might help me fix this.

Here's the part of the code from getting number of days to add to the end of loop:

```
    cin>>addDays;
    
    while (addDays > 0) {
        switch (month) {
            
            //months with 31 days
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            {
                finalDay = day + addDays;
                if (finalDay > 31) {
                    addDays = finalDay - 31;
                    month++;
                    day = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            
            //months with 30 days
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
            {
                finalDay = day + addDays;
                if (finalDay > 30) {
                    addDays = finalDay - 30;
                    month++;
                    day = 1;
                }
                break;
            }   
            
            //december
            case 12:
            {
                finalDay = day + addDays; //oggi è 10. Voglio aggiungere 30
                if (finalDay > 31) {       //40 è maggiore di 31
                    addDays = finalDay - 31;    //l'aggiunta 30 diventa 40 - 31 che fa 9
                    year++;
                    day = 1;
                    month = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            
            //february
            case 2:
            {
                finalDay = day + addDays;
                if (year % 4 == 0) {
                    if (finalDay > 29) {
                        addDays = finalDay - 29;
                        month++;
                        day = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (finalDay > 28) {
                        addDays = finalDay - 28;
                        month++;
                        day = 1;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop runs until `addDays` falls to `<= 0`.  The problem is, when you add `addDays` to `day`, if the resulting `finalDay` *IS* within the current `month`'s number of days, you *ARE NOT* breaking the loop, and you *ARE NOT* adjusting the values of `day` or `addDays` either, so the loop iterates again with the same `day` and `addDays` values, calculating the same `finalDay` value, over and over, endlessly.  That is why your program appears frozen.

After fixing that, you are also not taking into account the possibility that `addDays` might span more than a full month's worth of days.  The user could ask to add more than 1 month at a time.  So you need to adjust `addDays` more granularly per month.

Also, when the current `month` is `2` (February), your leap year calculation is incomplete. Being evenly divisible by `4` is not the only rule you need to check to know if the `year` is a leap year.  A `year` that is evenly divisible by `4` and `100` but not evenly divisible by `400` is not a leap year.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    return ((year % 4) == 0) &&
           (((year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0));
}

int lastDayInMonth(int year, int month)
{
    switch (month) {
            
        //months with 31 days
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            return 31;
            
        //months with 30 days
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            return 30;
            
        //month with 28 or 29 days
        case 2:
            return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
int year, month, day, addDays, lastDay;
...
cin >> addDays;
    
while (addDays > 0) {

    lastDay = lastDayInMonth(year, month);

    day += addDays;
    if (day <= lastDay) break;

    addDays -= (lastDay - day);

    if (++month == 13) {
        ++year;
        month = 1;
    }
    day = 1;
}
```

That being said, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67578282/65863), which wraps up this kind of logic in a reusable `struct` named `Date` that has an overloaded `operator+=` for adding days.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help! You made me understand where the mistake was. I've fixed it and it now works perfectly. But because I'm not as experienced as you and I was having difficulties to read that code, instead of doing as you did, I've added an `else` to every `if` inside the `switch`, which resets `addDays` to 0, because assignment statements copy their value, they don't move it, for some reasons I wasn't thinking about this stupid and basic thing.

And also thanks for letting me notice about the uncomplete leap year algorithm.
Here's the fixed code. Have a good day!

```
cin>>addDays;
        
        while (addDays > 0) {
            switch (month) {
                
                //months with 31 days
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 10:
                {
                    finalDay = day + addDays;
                    if (finalDay > 31) {
                        addDays = finalDay - 31;
                        month++;
                        day = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        addDays = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                
                //months with 30 days
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 9:
                case 11:
                {
                    finalDay = day + addDays;
                    if (finalDay > 30) {
                        addDays = finalDay - 30;
                        month++;
                        day = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        addDays = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                }   
                
                //december
                case 12:
                {
                    finalDay = day + addDays; //oggi è 10. Voglio aggiungere 30
                    if (finalDay > 31) {       //40 è maggiore di 31
                        addDays = finalDay - 31;    //l'aggiunta 30 diventa 40 - 31 che fa 9
                        year++;
                        day = 0;
                        month = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        addDays = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                
                //february
                case 2:
                {
                    finalDay = day + addDays;
                    if ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))) {
                        if (finalDay > 29) {
                            addDays = finalDay - 29;
                            month++;
                            day = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            addDays = 0;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        if (finalDay > 28) {
                            addDays = finalDay - 28;
                            month++;
                            day = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            addDays = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```